# Problem related to multiple integral

Tags: integration

$g : \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}^{3} $ be a function defined by $g(x,y,z) = (3y+4z, 2x-3z, x+3y).$

Also let $S = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: 0\leq x \leq 1, 0\leq y \leq 1, 0\leq z\leq 1 \}$

Now the question is

> If $$\int\int\int_{g(s)}(2x+y-2z)dxdydz = \alpha\int\int\int_{s}zdxdydz,$$ then $\alpha = ?$

The way I was thinking was not taking me too far. I was thinking $(3y+4z,2x-3z,x+3y) =(u,v,w)$ and was considering the scenario to be a change of variables like scenario but it's fruitless.

Can anyone guide me ? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this is a nice change of variables problem. It's a bit confusing to use the same variables for both sides of the equation though.

After setting $(3y+4z,2x−3z,x+3y)=(u,v,w)$, the left hand side of the equation should be written using these coordinates. It is then very easy to see :
$ 2u + v -2w = 5z$. Do not forget to include the determinant of the transformation $g$ in your final answer.

Comment: ah ! I see. O e thing, by equation you mean the integral one, right ?

Comment: Yes. The one that has triple integrals on both sides.

Comment: But then I would have to change the $dxdydz$ according to the settings.

Comment: Exactly, the left hand side should be: $\int_{g(S)} (2u+v−2w) du dv dw $